# Ordinal Logistic Regression giving illogical results

Tags: r, logistic-regression, ordinal

I made a OLR model using polr(). The dependent variable is the outcome of the match. A home win is a 2, a draw 1 and an away win (=home loss) is 0. 
I checked the assumptions (multi-collinearity, proportional odds...) and they seem fine.
However, when I run the model I get some illogical dependent coefficients.
The red cards, for example, give the opposite of what can be expected: red cards for the home team have a positive significant coefficient, while red cards for the away team have a negative significant coefficient. 
I checked the data and it doesn't seem like the red cards are swapped, they belong to the right teams. Furthermore, it seems like most times the team with the red card doesn't win too. 1300 of the 7300 matches have red cards, so it doesn't seem like they are underrepresented either.
Am I missing something here? What did I do wrong?

Here is some code:

```
m4_test <- polr(WHOWINS ~  H_NUMBER_RED + A_NUMBER_RED + H_Pts_Percentage_EUR + A_Pts_Percentage_EUR,data=basetable4_reg, Hess=TRUE)
#Get the p-values
#Store the coefficient table
m4.coef_test <- data.frame(round(coef(summary(m4_test)),5))
#Calculate and store p values
m4.coef_test$pval <- pnorm(abs(m4.coef_test$t.value),lower.tail=F)*2
m4.coef_test
#Visualize table
stargazer(m4_test,type="html",out="m4_test.htm")
```

The results are:

```
summary(m4_test)
Call:
polr(formula = WHOWINS ~ H_NUMBER_RED + A_NUMBER_RED + H_Pts_Percentage_EUR + 
    A_Pts_Percentage_EUR, data = basetable4_reg, Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                        Value Std. Error t value
H_NUMBER_RED          0.84042   0.079512  10.570
A_NUMBER_RED         -0.72626   0.074311  -9.773
H_Pts_Percentage_EUR -0.05309   0.001499 -35.417
A_Pts_Percentage_EUR  0.05027   0.001432  35.101

Intercepts:
    Value    Std. Error t value 
2|1  -0.4215   0.0895    -4.7094
1|0   1.0331   0.0905    11.4210

Residual Deviance: 13188.37 
AIC: 13200.37
```

Table with p values:

```
m4.coef_test
                        Value Std..Error   t.value          pval
H_NUMBER_RED          0.84042    0.07951  10.56966  4.119855e-26
A_NUMBER_RED         -0.72626    0.07431  -9.77314  1.468294e-22
H_Pts_Percentage_EUR -0.05309    0.00150 -35.41694 9.368040e-275
A_Pts_Percentage_EUR  0.05027    0.00143  35.10123 6.455702e-270
2|1                  -0.42150    0.08950  -4.70938  2.484714e-06
1|0                   1.03306    0.09045  11.42103  3.283196e-30
```

The structure is as follows:

```
str(basetable4_reg)
'data.frame':   7913 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ H_NUMBER_RED        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A_NUMBER_RED        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ H_Pts_Percentage_EUR: num  33.3 0 0 0 33.3 ...
 $ A_Pts_Percentage_EUR: num  33.3 100 100 100 33.3 ...
 $ WHOWINS             : Factor w/ 3 levels "2","1","0": 2 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 2 2 ...
```

Furthermore, I have found using the graphical method for checking proportional odds assumption that the values were red cards=2/3 or yellow=7/8, the proportional odds assumption does not hold. Could this be the cause of my weird results? And can I still look at other variables were the assumption does seem to hold?
Code for proportional odds assumption(with all variables included):

```
basetable4_reg_num <- basetable4_reg
basetable4_reg_num$WHOWINS <- as.numeric(levels(basetable4_reg_num$WHOWINS))[basetable4_reg_num$WHOWINS]
#Last assumption: proportional odds
#The relationship between each pair of outcome groups has to be the same
sf <- function(y) {
  c('Y>=0' = qlogis(mean(y >= 0)),
    'Y>=1' = qlogis(mean(y >= 1)),
    'Y>=2' = qlogis(mean(y >= 2)))
}

#Filter out some unusual matches (8yellows,3 reds for 1 team)
basetable4_reg_num <- dplyr::filter(basetable4_reg_num, H_NUMBER_YELLOW != 8 & A_NUMBER_YELLOW != 8 & H_NUMBER_RED != 3 & A_NUMBER_RED != 3)
(s4 <- with(basetable4_reg_num, summary(WHOWINS ~ spi1 + spi2 + H_NUMBER_YELLOW + H_NUMBER_RED + A_NUMBER_YELLOW + A_NUMBER_RED + H_cluster_2 + A_cluster_2 +
                                          H_cluster_3 + A_cluster_3 + H_Pts_Percentage_EUR + A_Pts_Percentage_EUR + H_STRONG_OPPONENT + 
                                          A_STRONG_OPPONENT + Rest_Difference_EUR +  H_FORM_EUR + A_FORM_EUR + H_break_EUR + A_break_EUR + 
                                          H_START_H_EUR + A_START_H_EUR  + H_carryover_EUR + A_carryover_EUR + H_SPI_First5 + A_SPI_First5, fun=sf)))

s4[, 4] <- s4[, 4] - s4[, 3]
s4[, 3] <- s4[, 3] - s4[, 3]
s4
plot(s4, which=1:3, pch=1:3, xlab='logit', main=' ',xlim=range(s4[,3:4]))
```

Output:

```
WHOWINS     N= 7908 

+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|                    |            |N   |Y>=0|Y>=1|Y>=2      |
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|spi1                |[15.9,53.0) |1977|Inf |0   |-1.0569194|
|                    |[53.0,63.0) |1979|Inf |0   |-1.0161198|
|                    |[63.0,73.3) |1975|Inf |0   |-1.0895256|
|                    |[73.3,96.6] |1977|Inf |0   |-1.0642268|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|spi2                |[15.9,52.5) |1978|Inf |0   |-1.0419683|
|                    |[52.5,62.5) |1979|Inf |0   |-1.1741643|
|                    |[62.5,72.7) |1975|Inf |0   |-1.0844946|
|                    |[72.7,96.8] |1976|Inf |0   |-0.9532292|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_NUMBER_YELLOW     |0           |1230|Inf |0   |-0.9611662|
|                    |1           |2195|Inf |0   |-0.9644353|
|                    |2           |2248|Inf |0   |-1.0575133|
|                    |3           |1355|Inf |0   |-1.0423640|
|                    |4           | 622|Inf |0   |-1.1662965|
|                    |5           | 177|Inf |0   |-1.0883802|
|                    |6           |  71|Inf |0   |-0.9221403|
|                    |7           |  10|Inf |0   |-0.9808293|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_NUMBER_RED        |0           |7264|Inf |0   |-1.0072793|
|                    |1           | 607|Inf |0   |-1.2562432|
|                    |2           |  37|Inf |0   |-1.6137763|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_NUMBER_YELLOW     |0           | 834|Inf |0   |-0.8696210|
|                    |1           |1901|Inf |0   |-0.9520453|
|                    |2           |2285|Inf |0   |-0.9992627|
|                    |3           |1650|Inf |0   |-1.0768545|
|                    |4           | 827|Inf |0   |-1.1357586|
|                    |5           | 299|Inf |0   |-1.0880402|
|                    |6           |  92|Inf |0   |-1.1409147|
|                    |7           |  20|Inf |0   |-2.0053336|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_NUMBER_RED        |0           |7042|Inf |0   |-0.9986183|
|                    |1           | 815|Inf |0   |-1.2406663|
|                    |2           |  51|Inf |0   |-1.9076889|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_cluster_2         |No          |7768|Inf |0   |-1.0091839|
|                    |Yes         | 140|Inf |0   |-1.0332204|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_cluster_2         |No          |7780|Inf |0   |-1.0105230|
|                    |Yes         | 128|Inf |0   |-0.9363063|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_cluster_3         |No          |1992|Inf |0   |-1.0146787|
|                    |Yes         |5916|Inf |0   |-1.0508935|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_cluster_3         |No          |2008|Inf |0   |-0.9388268|
|                    |Yes         |5900|Inf |0   |-1.1029711|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_Pts_Percentage_EUR|[ 0.0, 34.2)|2133|Inf |0   |-1.2214355|
|                    |[34.2, 44.7)|1858|Inf |0   |-1.2183999|
|                    |[44.7, 60.2)|1966|Inf |0   |-1.0843063|
|                    |[60.2,100.0]|1951|Inf |0   |-1.1211798|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_Pts_Percentage_EUR|[ 0.0, 34.2)|2339|Inf |0   |-1.5060732|
|                    |[34.2, 43.5)|1618|Inf |0   |-1.1830666|
|                    |[43.5, 58.5)|2007|Inf |0   |-1.0830832|
|                    |[58.5,100.0]|1944|Inf |0   |-1.0057895|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_STRONG_OPPONENT   |No          |5829|Inf |0   |-1.1251621|
|                    |Yes         |2079|Inf |0   |-0.9843824|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_STRONG_OPPONENT   |No          |5797|Inf |0   |-1.0614260|
|                    |Yes         |2111|Inf |0   |-1.1012423|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|Rest_Difference_EUR |[-158, 0)   |2501|Inf |0   |-1.0896414|
|                    |   0        |2995|Inf |0   |-1.0013136|
|                    |   1        |1525|Inf |0   |-0.9891562|
|                    |[   2,93]   | 887|Inf |0   |-0.9629256|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_FORM_EUR          |[ 0.0, 33.3)|2450|Inf |0   |-1.0091252|
|                    |[33.3, 50.0)|2374|Inf |0   |-1.0757834|
|                    |[50.0, 66.7)|1221|Inf |0   |-1.1282879|
|                    |[66.7,100.0]|1863|Inf |0   |-0.9635144|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_FORM_EUR          |[ 0.0, 33.3)|2263|Inf |0   |-1.0342653|
|                    |[33.3, 50.0)|2357|Inf |0   |-1.0422817|
|                    |[50.0, 73.3)|1990|Inf |0   |-1.0846315|
|                    |[73.3,100.0]|1298|Inf |0   |-0.9889462|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_break_EUR         |No          |6536|Inf |0   |-1.0147032|
|                    |Yes         |1372|Inf |0   |-0.9930284|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_break_EUR         |No          |6591|Inf |0   |-1.0197689|
|                    |Yes         |1317|Inf |0   |-0.9578141|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_START_H_EUR       |No          |3882|Inf |0   |-1.0048689|
|                    |Yes         |4026|Inf |0   |-1.0160930|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_START_H_EUR       |No          |3978|Inf |0   |-1.0027812|
|                    |Yes         |3930|Inf |0   |-1.0159319|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_carryover_EUR     |[ 20.9,105) |1977|Inf |0   |-0.9494935|
|                    |[105.1,124) |1980|Inf |0   |-1.0342376|
|                    |[124.4,141) |1974|Inf |0   |-1.0134742|
|                    |[141.1,191] |1977|Inf |0   |-1.0487209|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_carryover_EUR     |[ 23,106)   |1979|Inf |0   |-0.9280581|
|                    |[106,125)   |1976|Inf |0   |-1.0737660|
|                    |[125,142)   |1976|Inf |0   |-0.9633857|
|                    |[142,191]   |1977|Inf |0   |-1.0930709|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|H_SPI_First5        |[158,277)   |1985|Inf |0   |-0.9429083|
|                    |[277,319)   |1980|Inf |0   |-1.0571709|
|                    |[319,348)   |1977|Inf |0   |-1.0758229|
|                    |[348,402]   |1966|Inf |0   |-0.9636855|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|A_SPI_First5        |[158,274)   |1982|Inf |0   |-0.9420248|
|                    |[274,318)   |1984|Inf |0   |-1.0908272|
|                    |[318,347)   |1968|Inf |0   |-0.9653452|
|                    |[347,402]   |1974|Inf |0   |-1.0389595|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
|Overall             |            |7908|Inf |0   |-1.0092373|
+--------------------+------------+----+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Bebeerna, welcome to SO. Please show some sample data and share (part) of your code, so that we are able to understand your problem. Without data and code the only option is to guess a solution.

Comment: @MartinGal thank you, I added the code that got me the regression table. If other data is needed, please feel free to ask.

Comment: That's better---there's nothing obviously wrong with the code you show, so we'll need more info since we can't see the input or the results. Please do add some sample data. It would also help if you could isolate or simplify the problem a bit so you're not sharing 20+ columns of data with us. Since red cards are the problem you mention, perhaps we can focus on them. Try fitting the model `WHOWINS ~ H_NUMBER_RED + A_NUMBER_RED`, maybe including one or two other variables that are strongly predictive. Then you can also share the estimated coefficients `m4.coef`...

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the structure of your data, `str(basetable4_reg)`. If we still can't see any problems from that, we may need you to share a sample of your data, like `dput(basetable4_reg[1:20, c("WHOWINS", "H_NUMBER_RED", "A_NUMBER_RED")])` for the first 20 rows of those most relevant columns.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you. I have tried to add everything you asked. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: @GregorThomas This seems to have solved the problem. Thank you so very much! Now there are ofcourse variables who first seemed to be okay that now are the other way around (but they are MUCH easier to explain why they are 'illogical' so it is less of a problem). Could you give the above as answer so I can indicate it as the right answer? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of your response are in the wrong order.

Your `str` shows `WHOWINS: Factor w/ 3 levels "2","1","0"`, which means `"2"` comes before `"1"` comes before `"0"`. So the positive coefficient for `H_NUMBER_RED` is pulling away from the "low" 2 value up towards the "high" 0 value. Try `basetable4_reg = factor(basetable4_reg, levels = c("0", "1", "2"), ordered = TRUE)` to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I could ask one more thing: now, it seems like one of my most important variables receives the 'illogical' conclusion. It is the rating of teams, which is based on value and performance. A higher rating actually decreases the odds of winning now:
                        Value Std..Error   t.value          pval
spi1                 -0.02147    0.00412  -5.21675  1.820898e-07
spi2                  0.01292    0.00413   3.12720  1.764798e-03

Could you know a possible cause?

Comment: Also, I would like to add that the correlation between that SPI rating and other performance/value variables (form/pts_percentage/cluster) are all below 0.70, so there should be no multicollinearity which is also shown by the VIF values.

Comment: (a) make sure your SPIs are correct. (b) It seems strange to essentially use each SPI independently of each other. I would think perhaps the **difference** in SPIs between the two teams would make more sense than a linear coefficient for each of them. (Or perhaps even the ratio or log ratio). If two strong (or two weak) teams play each other, then you shouldn't expect the SPI ratings to offer much predictive value.

Comment: Thanks again Mr. Thomas. So, you suggest taking the difference between the two teams and then taking the log for example? And would you then suggest the same for carryover and spi_first5, which are the sum of 2 respectively 5 SPI values?
And what about the performance (pts_percentage and form)? Should I make the same change for those?
Sorry for the many questions. I swear these will be the last ones. You have been of great help for me.

Comment: I would suggest trying  (a) `spi_diff = spi1 - spi2`, or (b) `spi_ratio = spi1 / spi2` or (c) `spi_log_diff = log(spi1) - log(spi2)` (which is equivalent to `log(spi1 / spi2)`, and seeing which one works best. I don't *really* know what SPI is, and I really don't understand your explanation *"which are the sum of 2 respectively 5 SPI values"*. Summing SPI values sounds strange to me--probably because I don't really know what SPI is. I also don't know what the definitions of `pts_percentage` and `form` are, so I can't really make recommendations there.

Comment: Mr. Thomas, thank you again. SPI is a rating to measure a team's strength taking into account offensive and defensive performance and the team's market value. Concerning summing up, this is done to get the strength values of the next and previous opponent of the current opponent(carryover) or the strength of a team's first five opponents (spi_first5). Pts_percentage is the % of the maximal points a team has obtained. Form is the same but only taking into account the last 5 matches.

Comment: @Mr. Thomas, I have tried changing the variables to the ones you suggested and did not see a great improve in prediction accuracy. However, taking out the SPI out of the model but taking the log difference of both the carryover and spi_first5 does seem to make the model as good as without SPI. I guess I will keep the SPI out of the model to improve the interpretation.